# iOS:use masonry in awakeFromNib did not work for me

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, masonry

Here is code

```
@interface ContactsViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *numLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *addBtn;

@end


@implementation ContactsViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    [self.nameLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.mas_equalTo(16);
        make.top.mas_equalTo(12);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(20);
        make.right.mas_equalTo(-80);
    }];

    [self.numLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.nameLabel.mas_left);
        make.top.mas_equalTo(self.nameLabel.bottom).offset(-4);
        make.width.equalTo(self.nameLabel.mas_width);
        make.height.equalTo(self.nameLabel.mas_height);
    }];

    [self.addBtn mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.mas_equalTo(56);
        make.right.mas_equalTo(-16);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(32);
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_centerY);
    }];
}
```

but the frame of all these subviews in the cell did not change after executing, still is the initialized state. how to fix?

[size in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uluIa.png)

Comment: Are the `IBOutlet`s connected?

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: @Arun no, I am using xib